# Why is my data not getting stored in the LocalStorage after the refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using localStorage to store my data locally. I can see the defined object but when I add a value and then refresh the page, the new added data is lost and is not stored. What could be the problem?

https://codesandbox.io/s/todolistmax-9ng5fx?file=/src/App.js

This is the link to my codesandbox. After refresh, the newly entered data is lost and is not saved.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you have a `useEffect` that is always firing and overriding the `localStorage`. Also, you should save modified course goal in `localStorage` every time you do an action:

**Bonus**
I reworked some of your modifying code ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todolistmax-forked-yt73vl?file=/src/App.js))

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CourseList from "./components/CourseList";

import CourseInput from "./components/CourseInput";
const dummy_data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Do all React Exercises"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Learn more Javascript"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [courseGoal, setCourseGoal] = useState(dummy_data);
  console.log(courseGoal);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_LIST_OF_GOALS");
    if (data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      setCourseGoal(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  const setGoalsInLocalStorage = (goals) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("MY_LIST_OF_GOALS", JSON.stringify(goals));
  };

  const addGoalHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setCourseGoal((prevGoal) => {
      const newArray = [enteredText, ...prevGoal]
      setGoalsInLocalStorage(newArray);

      return newArray;
    });
  };

  const deleteGoalHandler = (id) => {
    setCourseGoal((prevGoal) => {
      const updatedGoal = prevGoal.filter((goal) => goal.id !== id);
      setGoalsInLocalStorage(updatedGoal);
      return updatedGoal;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CourseInput onAddGoal={addGoalHandler} />
      <h1>Course List</h1>
      <CourseList items={courseGoal} onDelete={deleteGoalHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

App.js

The problem is that the useEffect hook that saves data to localStorage runs on every state change. To fix it, add an empty dependency array [] as the second argument to the useEffect hook that saves to localStorage. This ensures it runs only once on mount and won't overwrite your data on subsequent updates.

Without a dependency array, the useEffect hook will run after every render,

so updated useEffect hook is

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_LIST_OF_GOALS");
    if (data) {
      setCourseGoal(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this runs only once on mount

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("MY_LIST_OF_GOALS", JSON.stringify(courseGoal));
  }, [courseGoal]); // Save to localStorage whenever courseGoal changes
```

Comment: Muhammad, this will not work as you are expecting it. The second `useEffect` will always run at the beginning and override the current localStorage with the initial state mentioned in the original problem.